# TypeError: jQuery("#slider-full").revolution is not a function

Tags: javascript, wordpress, slider, typeerror

Hi when I install worpdress and template with slider in console I got this error: **TypeError: jQuery("#slider-full").revolution is not a function. (In 'jQuery("#slider-full").revolution', 'jQuery("#slider-full").revolution' is undefined)** What should I do now?

```
jQuery("#slider-full").revolution({
    sliderType:"standard",
    sliderLayout:"fullscreen",
    dottedOverlay:"none",
    delay:9000,
    navigation: {
        keyboardNavigation:"off",
        keyboard_direction: "horizontal",
        mouseScrollNavigation:"off",
        onHoverStop:"off",
        touch:{
            touchenabled:"on",
            swipe_threshold: 75,
            swipe_min_touches: 50,
            swipe_direction: "horizontal",
            drag_block_vertical: false
        }
        ,
        arrows: {
            style:"",
            enable:true,
            hide_onmobile:false,
            hide_onleave:true,
            hide_delay:200,
            hide_delay_mobile:1200,
            tmp:'',
            left: {
                h_align:"left",
                v_align:"center",
                h_offset:20,
                v_offset:0
            },
            right: {
                h_align:"right",
                v_align:"center",
                h_offset:20,
                v_offset:0
            }
        }
        ,
        bullets: {
            enable:true,
            hide_onmobile:true,
            hide_under:769,
            style:"",
            hide_onleave:false,
            direction:"horizontal",
            h_align:"right",
            v_align:"top",
            h_offset:60,
            v_offset:40,
            space:5,
            tmp:'<span class="tp-bullet-image"></span><span class="tp-bullet-title"></span>'
        }
    },
    responsiveLevels:[1240,1024,778,480],
    visibilityLevels:[1240,1024,778,480],
    gridwidth:[1240,1024,778,480],
    gridheight:[868,768,960,720],
    lazyType:"none",
    parallax: {
        type:"scroll",
        origo:"slidercenter",
        speed:400,
        levels:[5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,55],
        type:"scroll",
    },
    shadow:0,
    spinner:"spinner2",
    stopLoop:"off",
    stopAfterLoops:-1,
    stopAtSlide:-1,
    shuffle:"off",
    autoHeight:"off",
    fullScreenAutoWidth:"off",
    fullScreenAlignForce:"off",
    fullScreenOffsetContainer: "",
    fullScreenOffset: "",
    disableProgressBar:"on",
    hideThumbsOnMobile:"off",
    hideSliderAtLimit:0,
    hideCaptionAtLimit:0,
    hideAllCaptionAtLilmit:0,
    debugMode:false,
    fallbacks: {
        simplifyAll:"off",
        nextSlideOnWindowFocus:"off",
        disableFocusListener:false,
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This means that your `RevolutionSlider` is not properly included into the page or it is included after the point at which it is called.

You must check in admin panel if this plugin is installed and turned on successfully.

If yes, you can try to run `jQuery("#slider-full").revolution({});` in your console to check if slider is not included later in the code;

Comment: For me $("#rev_slider").revolution({}); works in console but not when I call it in ngAfterViewInit()

It throws error "jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__(...).revolution is not a function"

Comment: Though https://stackoverflow.com/a/52843346/5131977 worked for me, but this answer explains why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

do this :

```
declare var jQuery: any;
```

instead of :

```
import $ as jquery
```

and use `ngAfterViewInit`

finally

```
jQuery(this.rev_slider.nativeElement).show().revolution(RevSliderConfig)
```

RevSliderConfig is the object of config

rev_slider is the id of the rev slider in html using `ViewChild`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and in my case, it was being caused by including jQuery twice.

Make sure that you have not included jQuery twice. Check all the scripts that are included on your page and ensure that none of them is including jquery already.

As an example in Laravel, a jquery library is already in public/js/app.js if you add a theme to your Laravel installation the theme might come with its jQuery library for use on some pages. Just make sure that when you are integrating your theme into your Laravel app you include one jQuery.